# The response HTML is repeating lines

Tags: java

I want to get the response HTML of aliexpress and it is working but when I try to load  the code in the browser it seems like it is repeated many times in the same onglet

```
package scrape;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Scrape {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ProtocolException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        URL url;
        url = new URL("https://best.aliexpress.com");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream())) ;
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            content.append(inputLine);
            System.out.println(content);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's an onglet?

Comment: No it isn't. You are displaying the accumulated content for every line, which necessarily includes the previous lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to the `StringBuffer` in the loop and printing it everytime.

To fix the problem, move the print statement to be outside the loop:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: Ohhh Thanks Forget That :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because, when you output the contents, you output `content` instead of the `inputLine`. That means that, when you get inputs like so:

> Line1
>   Line2
>   Line3

Your output will look like:

> Line1
>   Line1Line2
>   Line1Line2Line3

To achieve the desired output, you can instead print the line every iteration, like so:

```
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {
    content.append(inputLine);
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

**Output:**

> Line1
>   Line2
>   Line3

Otherwise, you can print the full output at the end of iteration, like so:

```
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
System.out.println(content);
```

This will get you the output:

> Line1Line2Line3

Now, if you want to split this input by line, you can just add a line separator between inputs:

```
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {
    if(content.length() != 0) {
        content.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    content.append(inputLine);
}
System.out.println(content);
```

This should get you the output:

> Line1
>   Line2
>   Line3

Comment: thnks  bro  ;) :)